# A variation problem from Brilliant

Tags: combinatorics

I can't solve this Brilliant challenge, and since explanations are no longer available for me, I'm asking for your help

We have $b1, b2, b0$ (no bus), $m1, m2, m3, m4, m0 $ (no museum), $p1, p2, p0$  (no palace). So if no extra conditions are applied, we have $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 = 45$ options. Then we reckon for the first qualification. $2$ bus options (the condition is not applied to no bus) $\cdot$ $5$ museum options $\cdot$ $3$ palace options is $10$ options more than $(4 + 3 + 2 + 1$ museum pairs) $\cdot$ $2$ bus options so we substract that $(30 - 20 = 10)$ and get $35$. Then we consider for the second "but", subtract $3$ more options $(b1m1p1, b2m1p1, b3m1p1)$, and get $32$. It's not among the listed answers (the number's way bigger). Where's my mistake(s)?

[image]

> Tourists visiting Brilliantia can buy the Brilliant Pass, which offers discounted access to many attractions. In the basic package, you need to pick one of two bus tours, one of four museums, and one of two palaces.
>
> For logistical reasons, if you opt for the bus tour of Brilliant City, you have to skip palaces but will visit two museums instead of one. Also, if you choose the Museum of Brilliance, the only palace you could visit is the Palace of Probability (if you haven't chosen the bus tour of Brilliant City).
>
> Assuming the order of attractions doesn't matter, in how many ways can you spend your weekend in Brilliantia?

Comment: There is no option not to take a bus $b0$, or not to visit a museum $m0$

Comment: @Andrei What makes you think so? If they say no bus gives you the advantage of being able to see palaces, then it's an option

Comment: "you need to pick one of two bus tours"